# Best way to mock out StringIO input for Ruby unit test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-1.9.3, stringio

Is there a better way to mock out StringIO input? I'm specifically looking for a way to avoid having to call the .rewind method. I tried using the block form of StringIO.open but it zeros out the internal string when returning it.

```
test_input = StringIO.new
test_input.puts '### Functional Tags'
test_input.puts '"@api"   *Workflow API*'
test_input.puts '"@categorize"'
test_input.puts ''
test_input.puts '"@combine"'
test_input.puts '"@flaky"  *delicate tests*'
test_input.rewind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
test_input = StringIO.new <<-RUBY
### Functional Tags'
"@api"   *Workflow API*
"@categorize"

"@combine"
"@flaky"  *delicate tests*
RUBY
```

Comment: Perfect, but I had an additional question. Does this work by creating a string literal with the heredoc syntax and then pass it into StringIO's new method?